# How to pass variable content from csv file to another file using batch file

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

For example I have a .csv file name "sample.csv" that reads every row.Now I want to pass the contents of the sample.csv to another file "pass.txt"

```
(
FOR /F "tokens=1-18* delims=," %%A IN ('type C:\Users\sample.csv') DO (
  set A = %%A
  set B = %%B


  echo %%~A
  echo %%~B

 )
)>youroutputfilename
pause
```

I can generate another text file using the above code. However what if I want to pass the content of "A" and "B" to another file?

Sample content of pass.txt before script is run:

```
Put A content Here: 
Put B content Here:
```

How to do this using batch file?

Sample output after run should be:

```
Put A content Here: **Apple** 
Put B content Here: **Banana**
```

Comment: `echo Put A content Here: %%~A`? (btw. your `set`-commands are useless. And wrong)

Comment: @Stephan Do I need to change the redirection command ">youroutputfilename". Im really new in batch file

Comment: `>` is the redirection. `youroutputfilename` is your output filename. I think, you want to redirect to `pass.txt`, so redirect with: `>pass.txt` (will write to the current directory)

Comment: @Stephan sorry i missed to replace that one. Yes but ">" will create new file right? I've tried your suggestion but it's not working

Comment: yes, `>` overwrites, `>>` appends. What exactly is "it's not working"?

Comment: @Stephan in this case, "pass.txt" already have contents inside the file, I need to display the variable content from batch file into pass.txt like the sample above.Put A content Here: Apple 
Put B content Here: Banana

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88075/discussion-between-peters-and-stephan).

Comment: Your problem and/or question is not properly thought out. What if your CSV file has multiple lines? What would the output look like then?

Comment: @dbenham  If that's the case, is it possible to assign the 2nd to nth line of the csv to another variable?

Answer (score 0):

please run this modified code and post it's output:

```
@echo off
set file=c:\users\sample.csv
if not exist %file% echo input file not found
(
 FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A IN (%file%) DO (
  echo Put A content Here: %%~A
  echo Put B content Here: %%~B
 )
)>pass.txt
type pass.txt
pause
```

Comment: "Put A content Here:" and "Put B content Here:" are already contents of pass.txt. I'll edit the question to avoid confusion